# Automate Splunk oneshot command with powershell

Tags: powershell, splunk

I am trying to write a powershell script that automates Splunk's `oneshot` command which will explicitly reindex a log file contained in a monitored directory.  Given a range of dates, the script will traverse the directory in which the log files are kept, and execute `oneshot` once for each file that targets that date (there are typically between 50 and 110 or so per day). I am definitely not what you would call a "powershell guru" by any means, which is what brings me here.

When taking a closer look, `Invoke-Expression` [seems to be](http://screencast.com/t/L8rpy63fDeeN) starting a separate cmd.exe instance each time it's called.  This results in either the splunkd daemon to crash, or for cmd.exe to crash.

That being said, are there better alternatives to using `Invoke-Expression`?  It appears that my script isn't waiting for each invoked expression to complete before it fires off the next one, and that is causing adverse effects on the server.  I've read this happens when using `Invoke-Expression` to call into external non-console applications. In this case, I'm calling into splunk.exe to execute the command, so that makes sense.

I am considering utilizing the scripting host instead of using `Invoke-Expression`, but first wanted to ask the pros here at StackOverflow for some potential alternatives :)

That being said, has anyone run into a similar problem in the past, and if so what alternative did you go with? Alternatively, are there other powershell tools I could use in place of `Invoke-Expression` that would not only do the job, but would provide more stable execution? Any help/suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: It turns out, it's not necessariily that I'm using Invoke-Expression.  It's the way Splunk handles the oneshot command.  Instead of indexing a series of files, it indexes all of them in parallel.  Therefore, if you try and 'oneshot' multiple .gz log files, it will try to decompress and parse them at the same time, which causes the splunkd daemon to crash.  I ended up regulating the number files being oneshot indexed at the same time, as well as the number of running splunkd indexer processes that are running at the same time and my script runs fine, it just takes longer to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following approach:

```
& cmd /c "full path to splunk.exe"
```

Comment: Same outcome.  Looking at using System.Diagnostics.Process to call into splunk.exe and execute the oneshot.

Comment: try start-process -filepath "path to splunk.exe" -NoNewWindow

Comment: Marking this question as the answer because it indeed is an alternative to Invoke-Expression, and also because it's not the use of that command that was causing cmd.exe/splunkd daemon to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do the "oneshot" from a command using the Splunk CLI , have you looked at the Splunk Powershell Resource Kit ?

https://github.com/splunk/splunk-reskit-powershell

Comment: I sure did. Although we use it for other splunk-related stuff, oneshot is the only way we've found that will explicitly re-index a file it's already attempted to index, aside from commands which alter the Tailing Processor's checksums for each file.